# How did Elsa win over the water spirit in "Frozen II"?

Tags: frozen-ii

During the course of *Frozen II*, Elsa, after nearly drowning in the waters of the Dark Sea,

> manages to make peace with the water spirit, who takes the form of a horse, and rides it to the island.

How does she manage to do that? As far as I can see,

> she only put reins on the horse and froze the water, which... doesn't seem like it'd be the best way to make friends with a free nature spirit.

We also see that later on, it's willing to come at the drop of a hat.

So... why did the actions she took work? How does she manage to win over the spirit?

Comment: Same way you tame a real horse, you submit it to your control. Helps that she's the Avatar too.

Comment: @Mooz - I though she was Captain Planet?

Answer (score 3):

The [junior novel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44908905-frozen-2) indicates that she '[broke](https://www.thesprucepets.com/what-is-broke-horse-1886596)' the Water Spirit by reining it in.

> Above the water, the Water Nokk grabbed Elsa’s arm and dragged her through the waves. She fought to breathe. Desperate, she used her magic to throw out an ice bridle. It hooked onto the Water Spirit’s mouth and head. She swung around and landed on the horse’s back.
>
> The Water Nokk panicked and bucked. But Elsa yanked on the reins and tried to gain control. The horse surfaced and turned toward the icy landmass that Elsa had seen in the distance. **It ran, fighting, trying to throw her off, refusing to give in to her commanding hold.**
>
> **Elsa pulled the reins tighter and pressed her legs down harder until the horse responded. Finally, its stride evened out and she relaxed her grip.** They moved together, Elsa and the Water Nokk.

Later they grow to respect and like each other. Not a relationship of equals, but a friendship nonetheless.

> Gale flipped around Elsa with a resounding yes, then swept past her to the Water Nokk, which rose out of a nearby stream. Bruni hopped down and headed for the rocks.
>
> “You ready?” Elsa asked her new friend. The Water Nokk stomped its hoof and shook its head yes. Elsa touched its forelock with her power and turned the Water Nokk into a mix of ice and snow. They touched foreheads fondly.